# Woocommerce/Wordpress: Simple Product Attribute Display

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**What I am trying to achieve:** Enable ‘Simple Product’ pages to display ‘Attributes’ (exactly as Variable Product Attributes are shown)

**What I already know:**
I know that it can be done by creating a Variable Product with just one variation instead of a Single Product. I have used Variable Products before and I don’t want to create 1 additional ID for every single simple product.

**Why am I trying this:** Weights shown on any product page is the shipping weight. I want to show the product actual weight and actual volume (eg 100ml). Volumes are not supported by default and I want a consistent/elegant way to show it to customers. Since I am already using attributes for Variable products, I can quickly reuse the same attribute values for Simple Products.

**What I don’t want to do:**
– Write volume in the Product header
– Create variable products with 1 variation

I am sure there are lots of people facing this issue and would like a good solution. I just need the Attribute values to be shown for Simple Products in the exact place as Variable Products. I can customize the css part.

I am comfortable editing functions.php

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: *"I don’t want to create 1 additional ID for every single simple product"* --  But are they the SAME?  I mean a t-shirt is available in red or green is technically the same product, but uses those different IDs to delineate whether it's a green on or a red one.   The different IDs is **what makes it variable**

Comment: @Zak: Yes, I am aware of that. Why I don't want to create IDs is that I work with updating the products in bulk via import and export csv. The variable nature of it creates one ID for the 'variable' and another ID for 'variation'. Then it gets difficult to mange as you'd have to update the product prices in the variation, but description in the variable!

Comment: $product->get_attribute('pa_attribute_name'); this will return your attribute. Depends on which part of the product you want to use it call your proper hook. Thats all.

Comment: @Snuffy: Thanks, I am very new to Wordpress and php so I don't have a clue where to call it. If I need to call below the title, what would be the code?

Also, if for certain products the attribute is 'Weight' and for others its 'Volume' - how do I make sure it automatically checks whichever is applicable and displays?

Comment: Use woo documentation to help you. Also this website have good visual examples - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the attributes after title we need to hook to `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action.

By default title is with priority of 5

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

In your child theme functions.php file add the following.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_attributes_after_title', 6 );
function show_attributes_after_title() {
    global $product; 
    $pa_weight = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_weight' ); //Make sure this is your attribute
    $pa_volume = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_volume' ); //Make sure this is your attribute
    if($pa_weight): 
        echo $pa_weight; 
    endif;
    if($pa_volume): 
        echo $pa_volume; 
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works as needed. But this shows the available options for both Simple and Variable products. Since I already have variation buttons for Variable products that exactly show the Weight/Volume, is there a way to only limit this to 'Simple Products only'

Comment: Got it! Added  >> 
    if( $product->is_type('simple') ):